# ¿Cómo Mostrar una menú según el usuario que inicio sesión en PHP?

Tags: php, session

Esta es mi primera pregunta por acá y tengo una comprensión media-baja con respecto a las sessiones espero me puedan ayudar, necesito mostrar un menú u otro dependiendo del rol de usuario que esta ingresando en el login.
lo que tengo realizado es lo siguiente:

login que detecta que rol esta ingresando y lo redirecciona al modulo correspondiente.
(tengo un archivo con rutas según el rol).

si el usuario "X" tiene el rol 1 se le muestra el modulo1 con el menu 1.

si el usuario "Y" tiene el rol 2 se le muestra el modulo2 con el menu 2.

el código que uso para hacer esto es el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION["venta"]){
    header("location:ingreso");
    exit();
}else{
    include"views/modules/Venta/botonera.php";
}
?>
```

el problema esta, que ahora tengo un rol 3 que necesita acceder a ciertas partes del modulo 1
y necesito mostrar el menú 3.
Para ello he intentado modificar el código anterior de esta forma:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION["rol1"]){
header("location:ingreso");
exit();
}else{
include"sidebar1.php";
} 
if(!$_SESSION["rol3"]){
header("location:ingreso");
exit(); 
}else{
include"sidebar3.php";
}
?>
```

con esa modificación no me deja ingresar y se queda en el login.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez deberias usar else if en lugar de if "separados"
algo como:

```
if(rol == 1){
 do_some();
}
else if( rol == 2){
    do_some();
}
else if (rol == 3){
    do_some();
}
else{
    header("location:ingreso");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para temas de perfiles de ingreso deberías realizar algo un poco mas complejo, pero el cual te permitirá la escalabilidad de tu sistema, primero que nada, cada modulo o página en tu sistema deberá estar identificada en las opciones de la tabla de usuarios así por ejemplo si tienes un modulo de venta esa modulo debería tener un campo en el cual registrar si tiene o no acceso dicho usuario a dicho modulo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En mi ejemplo en el registro de usuario tiene varios campos opt1....optN donde cada campo corresponde a un modulo o pagina dentro del sistema este campo tiene las opciones 0,1 ó 2 en donde 0 es sin acceso 1 es acceso de lectura y 2 acceso de escritura o modificación, luego al iniciar una sesión leerías las opciones del usuario logueado y en base a eso podrías restringir o permitir los módulos a los cuales ingresará.

```
<?php
$ventas = $_SESSION['opt1']; 
    if($ventas==1){
         echo '{ "href": "ventas_l.php", "text": "Ventas" },'; 
    } elseif($ventas==2) {
         echo '{ "href": "ventas.php", "text": "Ventas" },'; 
    }
 ?>
```

Si te fijas en muestra solo el menú en caso de que los valores sean 1 ó 2 en caso de ser 0 ni los muestra.

En todo caso para el tema particular que te aqueja es que estas mezclando los roles con los módulos si tienes predefinidos que según su rol tiene acceso a un determinado modulo entonces ese modulo no es independiente y depende de un rol y por lo tanto no es un modulo, una solución para tu caso es la siguiente:

```
<?php 
session_start();
@$rol= $_SESSION['rol'];

switch ($rol) {
    case 1: 
    header ("location:ingreso.php");
    break;
    case 2:
    header ("location:ventas.php");
    break;
    case 3:
    header ("location:insumos.php");
    break; 
}
?>
```

El error en tu código es

```
if(!$_SESSION["rol1"])
```

Ya que  if(!$_SESSION["rol1"]) siempre se cumple si tu variable es un string, la única vez que no se cumple es cuando es 0 has la prueba con el siguiente ej:

```
$a=0;
if(!$a) {
echo "Cumple";
} else {
echo "No Cumple"; 
}
```

Finalmente debes como dije en un principio diferenciar roles de módulos para resolver el problema. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En base a sus respuestas logre darme una mejor idea de como implementarlo.
Al final el código quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION){
    header("location:login");
    exit();
}else{
    if(isset($_SESSION["venta"])){
        include_once("views/modules/Venta/menu1.php");
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION["produccion"])) {
        include_once("views/modules/produccion/menu2.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo usaría una única variable de sesión, por ejemplo 'rol', y a ésta le asignaría el valor 'venta', 'produccion',... Y usaría un switch. Te pongo código en una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar eso deberías de implementar las vistas por módulos para así usar tus includes dependiendo del rol, adicional, como medida de seguridad, en cada modulo deberías de agregar la validación de rol que se ha guardado en SESSION. Yo lo tengo de esta forma:

```
ob_start();    
session_name('ingreso_usuario');    
session_start();    

if( isset($_SESSION['nom_usuario']) ){ //verificar si esta definida esta sesion
    $nombre_login = $_SESSION['nom_usuario'];
}else{
    $nombre_login = "No existe";
}

if( isset($_SESSION['rol_usuario']) ){
    $rol_login = $_SESSION['rol_usuario'];
}else{
    $rol_login = -1;
}

//para este caso, los roles los manejo por numeros, escuche que de esa forma es mas seguro
if( isset($_SESSION['nom_usuario']) && $_SESSION['rol_usuario']==1 ){

    include 'arriba.php';

...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Douglas Basándome en tu respuesta, yo mejor usaría una única variable de sesión, por ejemplo 'rol', y a ésta le asignaría el valor 'venta', 'produccion',... Y usaría un switch. Te pongo como quedaría:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION)) {
    header('Location:login');
    exit;
} else {
    switch ($_SESSION['rol']) {
        case 'venta':
            include_once 'views/modules/Venta/menu1.php';
            break;
        case 'produccion':
            include_once 'views/modules/produccion/menu2.php';
            break;
        default:
            //Por si quieres poner algo en caso de que no sea ninguno
            break;
    }
}
```